# in OpenCV is mask a bitwise and operation

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm starting with opencv in python and I have a questions about how mask is applied for

`bitwise_and(src1, src2, mask=mask)`

Which of these describes the implementation:

- A. all bitwise, mask first

  1. src1 is ANDed with mask
  2. src2 is ANDed with mask
  3. what's left of src1 and src2 are ANDed together
- B. all bitwise, images first

  1. src1 is ANDed with src2
  2. result is ANDed with mask
- C. conditional AND

  1. mask is "iterated" through (eg a loop)
  2. for each pixel in mask, if it's nonzero, then corresponding pixels in src1,src2 are ANDed and copied to output

I would think the performance characteristics of each could vary slightly.

Which of these (or how else) is the actual implementation?  (and why, if I may ask)

I was trying to look at the source, but couldn't quite make out what they did:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ca0b6fbb952899a1c7de91b909d3acd8e682cedf/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the docs, the 3rd parameter is a destination image which you missed.

This operation will change the values of the destination image only if the mask says so (in this case it will do the bitwise and of the two source images). For the pixels that are not in the mask, the destination will contain the same values that it contained before.

Comment: well, I'm actually using python and in python you can skip dest and it returns the modified image which in c++ will be in dest.   As to my question, you're suggesting option C, that it applies an actual "if() to each pixel in the mask before then doing bitwise on the corresponding pixels from src1 and src2.  But I don't see how you came to that conclusion.   Typically a mask is applied as a bitwise operation, so doing it with if(  is non-standard and I want to know if that's what opencv really does.

Comment: Yes, option C. Other options may give you the same results if all images are binary as your destination is all zeroes initially. I always use binary masks (black 0 and white 255 images, no gray values), I don't know what happens if you use a grayscale mask. Just be careful, "bitwise and" is doing an "and" _bit by bit_ (a pixel usually has 8 bits), if both src images are binary (0 and 255 values) everything will be OK, but if they have other pixel values, it will give you results that you are not expecting.

Answer (score 11):

I have worked out two implementations of `cv2.bitwise_and()` using color images and binary images.

**1. Using Binary Images**

Let us assume we have the following binary images:

*Screen 1:*

[image]

*Screen 2:*

[image]

Upon performing bitwise:

```
fin = cv2.bitwise_and(screen1, screen2)
cv2.imwrite("Final image.jpg", fin)
```

we obtain the following:

[image]

**2. Performing masking on color images:**

You can mask out a certain region of a given color image using the same function as well.

Consider the following image:

[image]

and consider *Screen 1* (given above) to be the mask

```
fin = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = screen1)
cv2.imwrite("Masked image.jpg", fin)
```

gives you:

[image]

***Note:*** While performing bitwise AND operation the images must have the same size

Comment: It's actually deeper than that.  For example I found ANDing two images literally ANDed the bits, so that if a pixel in one image was (50,50,50) and another was (150,150,150) the result was an entirely different color at each pixel (bitwise binary and).  However, in the mask parameter, colors like (50) or (150) are treated exactly the same, eg they are NOT ANDed at all. They are either thresholded at 0=0, 1-255=255  and then ANDed, or more likely, they are actually using an if statement per pixel.   Classically, masks were always applied as bitwise operations, but opencv seems not to.

Comment: hope you got what you needed though !!