# OpenCV Background Subtraction Get Color Objects (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

Background subtraction method (BackgroundSubtractorMOG2) will normally return the output in binary image.

Is there a solution on how I can get the original colour of the object after implementing the BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("people.mkv")
kernel_dil = np.ones((10,10), np.uint8)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=0, varThreshold=444, detectShadows=False)

while True:
     ret, frame1 = cap.read()
     frame = cv2.resize(frame1,(1364,700),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
     mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
     mask.fill(255)

     roi_corners = np.array([[(11,652), (1353,652), (940,84), (424,84)]], dtype=np.int32)
     cv2.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, 0)

     masking = cv2.bitwise_or(frame, mask)

     if ret == True:
         fgmask = fgbg.apply(masking,mask)
         fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
         dilation = cv2.dilate(fgmask2, kernel_dil, iterations = 1)
         (contours,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

          for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
              area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
              x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

              if(area>0.001):
                  cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
                  cv2.putText(frame, 'People', (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("FullScreen", frame)
cv2.imshow("FGMask1", fgmask)
cv2.imshow("FGMask2", dilation)

key = cv2.waitKey(12)
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the output as binary mask, you could just do a bitwise and with your original image

`cv.bitwise_and(input, input, mask = yourMOG_output);`

Comment: Hi im stil quite new in learning opencv, im sorry cause I dont get your answer. Im implementing the bitwise_or just to get my region of interest. After I implement the MOG, I want the extracted object to return the exact colour from the original frame, not white.

Comment: Ok, bitwise and between your image and a mask will return exactly what you look for. See this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920810/in-opencv-is-mask-a-bitwise-and-operation